# Show/Hide rows based on IIF statement in SSRS - issue when condition has a > value over 50000

Tags: reporting-services, logic, visibility, iif

I am trying to hide rows based on an `IIF` statement like below:

I go to `Group Properties` and then the `Visibility` tab to select `Show/Hide based on an expression`:

```
=iif(Fields!short_name.Value = "Checklist 1"
     AND 
     First(Fields!Checklist_Counter_1.Value, "DataSet1") >= 35000
    ,True
    ,False
    )
```

This works - however if i increase the `>35000` to `>50000` the logic no longer works, i have tried multiple variations and every only get an error when i set the > to `50000` or higher (`49999` works)

Any ideas how to lift this cap?

Comment: *the logic no longer works* -- What do you mean by this?  Do no rows get filtered out but the report still runs without issue?  Are errors being thrown?  If so, what is the error message?

Comment: I mean that the rows I want to hide are still visible, i want to hide rows that have a value of >80000 but can only use the above expression up to 49999

Comment: How are you specifying the link between these two datasets?  You are pulling the first  value from `DataSet1` but there is no instruction on how to order `DataSet1` so the right row is returned?

Comment: its all the one dataset, DataSet1 I'm asking that when the the Short_Name field is Checklist 1, look at the Checklist_Counter_1 column, if its >80000 hide 
the row, this works perfectly up to 49999

Comment: Because you are using the `First` function and a named `DataSet` you are not referring to the same row, but whichever happens to be on top at that time.  I would imagine that your results aren't perfect, but the lower threshold has a greater change of hiding rows.  Try using just `Fields!Checklist_Counter_1.Value >= 35000` instead

Comment: when i use that i get an error that its not the correct input string

Comment: If this is being set on the group properties then try taking the `, "DataSet1"` bit out. The FIRST context will then be the group context, which is what I think you want. basically just use `First(Fields!Checklist_Counter_1.Value)`

Comment: Thanks Alan but i still get the 'Input string was not in a correct format' error message